# Explicit solution of separable variable ODE y'(x) = |y(x)|(1-y(x)). Where am I wrong?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I know that the function

y(x) = k/(k+e<sup>-t</sup>)  solves the ODE y > 0

and

y(x) = 1/(1+ke<sup>t</sup>) solves the ODE  for y< 0

But when I solved the ODE I got a different result. I have clearly made some elementary mistakes but don't know where am I wrong and how to proceed further. Therefore I request anyone who can take a look and hint me anything on this.

For y > 0

$$\int \frac{1}y +\frac{1}{1-y} \, dy = \int dx $$

$$ ln\frac{|y|}{|1-y|} + C1 = x + C2 $$
$$ \frac{|y|}{|1-y|} = e^{x+c} $$
and I got stuck in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't really make out exactly what your original question was, but assuming you are correct at the point you are stuck,  you have if $0<y<1$ everything in the absolute value is positive and you can change the $e^c$ to a positive constant multiple $k$,  giving

$$\frac y {1 - y}=ke^x$$
then it's just algebra to multiply through by 1-y,  distribute,  and move the $y$ terms to one side, etc.
$$y=(1-y)ke^x$$
$$y=ke^x-yke^x$$
$$y+yke^x=ke^x$$
$$y(1+ke^x)=ke^x$$
$$y=\frac {ke^x} {1+ ke^x}$$
multiplying the top and bottom by $e^{-x}$ tranforms it to your form
$$y=\frac k {e^{-x} +k}$$
(albeit you used $x$ instead of $t$)
if $y>1$ then the denominator needs its sign flipped so you get to
$$\frac y {1 +y}=ke^x$$
which following along the signs just changes the denomonator in the final answer to a -,

$$y=\frac k {e^{-x}-k}$$
You get the same solution if $y<0$ as then just the numerator flips signs

Comment: Thank you, Alan. I understood now where I was wrong.

Comment: No problem, welcome to M.S.E.   If this answered your question, go ahead and mark the green check box to accept the answer.